# Summation in R inside function

Tags: r, function

I'm writing a function in R that has to compute the values of two vectors before going ahead and doing some other fancy stuff. The two vectors, R and B, are given by the following summations:

[image]

and

[image: $$ R(i)=\sum_{k=1}^{i-1}(t_i-t_k)e^{-\beta(t_i-t_k)} $$]

where $\beta$ is a constant and the *ts* are passed to the function and are the occurrence times of an event. So, basically, when the i-th event occurs (at time `t_i`), I compute `B(i)` and `R(i)` which are summations done using all the previous occurrence times `t_k` of my event up to that moment.

I would like to come up with something more efficient than this

```
r <- rep(0,length(t))
for(i in 2:length(t)) {
    r[i] <- sum((t[i]-t[which(t<t[i])])*exp(beta*(t[i]-t[which(t<t[i])])))
}
b <- rep(0,length(t))
for(i in 2:length(t)) {
    b[i] <- sum(((t[i]-t[which(t<t[i])])^2)*exp(beta*(t[i]-t[which(t<t[i])])))
}
```

which basically computes everything twice even though the only difference between the two is the square before the exponential. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: How big will `t` typically be? If it's not too big, you could use `outer` instead of those `for` loops.

Comment: @Hack-R They simply haven't provided an example of the vector `t`, so R thinks you want to subset the function `t`.

Comment: Uhhhh, these loops are ugly. Vectorization is the Name of the game... You should be using a dataframe with the columns being t_i and t_k. Then compute difference. Thereafter, use ifelse on the difference. This can be done without any loops and should be computed instantaneously.

Comment: `t` is rather big: several hundred thousands of entries... @Peter: I'm not sure I understand: should only make two columns? Also, in case it makes any difference, I have just added into the question the definition of what my `ts` are.

Comment: Ok, seems to be a bit more complex than I thought initially. Creating a matrix with the row-vector repeated in each row would avoid the loop, but the object would grow too large to be held in memory... Not a good case for brute force. Have you thought about sorting the original vector with the position 'i' preserved in a second column?

Comment: If that's really intended to be a sum over all elements of `tk` which are less than `ti`, then it's not a well-defined operation.  Is this supposed to be a sum over `ti[j]<tk[j]` ?  What is the index over which you wish to sum?

Comment: Then, it would amount to a cumsum operation, ... If you start with the largest element this should be doable in linear time, me thinks ;)

Comment: I'm going to bed ;) excited to see a solution by tomorrow @Carl_Witthoft

Comment: @Carl, at each occurrence time `t_i` (which denotes the i-th occurrence of an event), I will do the summation on all the occurrence times BEFORE time `t_i`, which I denoted as `t_k`.

Comment: Easy, if the t_k's are sorted ;)

Comment: @PeterLustig: I sort them when I pass them to the function :)

Comment: After looking a bit more closely into this, I belive @Carl_Witthoft is right. Are the equations really correct? Maybe you can give us also an intuition what the problem is really about?

Comment: @PeterLustig: I have edited the question to add more information about the problem. At each occurrence of my event, I compute `B` and `R` which use the previous occurrence times up to that moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the size of your input vector, you can't do better than using an explicit loop (otherwise you'd need too much memory). But obviously, you need only one loop and the problem is embarrassingly parallel.

This is my understanding of your problem:

```
library(doParallel)

cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)

fun_r <- function(t, beta) {
  res <- foreach(i = seq_along(t)[-1], .combine = cbind) %dopar% {
    d <- t[i] - t[seq_len(i - 1)]
    c(sum(d^2 * exp(-beta * d)),
      sum(d * exp(-beta * d)))
  }
  cbind(0, unname(res))
}

set.seed(42)
t <- sort(rnorm(1e4))

ttt <- fun_r(t, 0.5)
ttt[,1:10]
#     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]     [,10]
#[1,]    0 0.3223427 0.3571912 0.5101723 0.5369059 0.6072245 0.6420904 0.6625009 0.7287196 0.8478711
#[2,]    0 0.4800071 0.5391521 0.8341596 0.8901340 1.0569168 1.1455994 1.2034259 1.3972700 1.7177646

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(fun_r(t, 0.5), times=5)
#Unit: seconds
#         expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
#fun_r(t, 0.5) 5.538867 5.558164 5.562138 5.567474 5.642002     5

stopCluster(cl)
```

If this is still too slow, you can try implementing it with Rcpp.

Comment: Wow, I have learned a ton of new useful commands thanks to your answer (`seq_along`, `seq_len`, etc...) and `foreach` is a very interesting way of implementing a loop. Thank!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your equations correctly, you just need to compute `t[i] - t[1:i-1]` separately first, and then use those values in all subsequent calculations.

```
t <- rnorm(10)
i <- 10
beta <- 1

tdiffs <- t[i]-t[1:i-1]
betaexp <- exp(-beta*tdiffs)
B <- sum(tdiffs^2*betaexp)
R <- sum(tdiffs*betaexp)
```

Comment: That's my interpretation, too.  Hope it's what he wanted.